# How is the smooth dice loss differentiable?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am training a U-Net in keras by minimizing the `dice_loss` function that is popularly used for this problem: [adapted from here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3611) and [here](https://gist.github.com/wassname/7793e2058c5c9dacb5212c0ac0b18a8a)

```
def dsc(y_true, y_pred):
     smooth = 1.
     y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
     y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
     intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
     score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
     return score

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return (1 - dsc(y_true, y_pred))
```

This implementation is different from the [traditional dice loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) because it has a smoothing term to make it "differentiable". I just don't understand how adding the `smooth` term instead of something like `1e-7` in the denominator makes it better because it actually changes the loss values. I have checked this by using a trained unet model on a test set with a regular `dice` implementation as follows:

```
def dice(im1,im2):
     im1 = np.asarray(im1).astype(np.bool)
     im2 = np.asarray(im2).astype(np.bool)
     intersection = np.logical_and(im1, im2)
     return np.float(2. * intersection.sum()) / (im1.sum() + im2.sum() + 1e-7))
```

Can someone explain why the smooth dice loss is conventionally used?

Comment: Why do you believe that this `smooth` term makes the loss function differentiable?

Comment: Pretty sure I read it somewhere but I probably mixed up the concepts.

Comment: In 'smooth dice' the same thing as 'soft dice'?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck I believe so!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding `smooth` to the loss does not make it differentiable. What makes it differentiable is

1. Relaxing the threshold on the prediction: You do not cast `y_pred` to `np.bool`, but leave it as a *continuous* value between 0 and 1
2. You do not use set operations as `np.logical_and`, but rather use the element-wise product to approximate the non-differenetiable intersection operation.

You only add `smooth` to avoid division by zero when both `y_pred` and `y_true` do not contain any foreground pixels.

Comment: Thank you! I muddled everything in my head. Just to follow up, if I use a smooth term = 1 for training, should I use that same smooth = 1 for inference? I've originally used a very small value to avoid division by zero but having smooth =1 rather than 1e-7 seems to boost my results for the better

Comment: I suppose during inference you need to report the exact dice loss and not the smooth one. @nababs

Comment: @Shal,hello,for 'Relaxing the threshold',what do you mean?Do nothing,or clip it?

Comment: @AlexLuya you do not threshold at all- thresholding is not differentiable

Comment: @Shai,Thanks,I knew that,just be curious to want to know what kinds of 'relaxing threshold' is differentiable