# How to implement multi class dice loss function without using argmax function(argmax is not differentiable)?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a multi class dice loss function in tensorflow. Since it is multi class dice, I need to convert the probabilities of each class into its one-hot form. For example, if my network outputs these probabilities: 
[0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1] (assuming 4 classes) 
I need to convert this into:
[0 1 0 0]
This can be done by using *tf.argmax* followed by *tf.one_hot*

```
def generalized_dice_loss(labels, logits):
 #labels shape [batch_size,128,128,64,1] dtype=float32
 #logits shape [batch_size,128,128,64,7] dtype=float32
 labels=tf.cast(labels,tf.int32)
 smooth = tf.constant(1e-17)
 shape = tf.TensorShape(logits.shape).as_list()
 depth = int(shape[-1])
 labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth, dtype=tf.int32,axis=4)
 labels = tf.squeeze(labels, axis=5)
 logits = tf.argmax(logits,axis=4)
 logits = tf.one_hot(logits, depth, dtype=tf.int32,axis=4)
 numerator = tf.reduce_sum(labels * logits, axis=[1, 2, 3])
 denominator = tf.reduce_sum(labels + logits, axis=[1, 2, 3])
 numerator=tf.cast(numerator,tf.float32)
 denominator=tf.cast(denominator,tf.float32)
 loss = tf.reduce_mean(1.0 - 2.0*(numerator + smooth)/(denominator + smooth))
 return loss
```

Problem is, tf.argmax is not differentiable, It will throw an error:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

How to solve this problem? Can we do the same thing without using tf.argmax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [How is the smooth dice loss differentiable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973856/how-is-the-smooth-dice-loss-differentiable). You won't need to do the conversion (convert `[0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1]` to `[0 1 0 0]`). Just leave them as the continuous value between 0 and 1.

If I understand correctly, the loss function is just a surrogate to achieve your expected objective. Even though it is not the same, as long as it is a good proxy, it is fine (otherwise, it is not differentiable).

In the evaluation time, feel free to use the `tf.argmax` to get the real metric.