# Intersection over Union used as Metric or Loss

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

Im currently struggling to understand the use of the IoU. Is the IoU just a Metric to monitor the quality of a network, or is used as a loss function where the value has some impact on the backprop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For a measure to be used as a loss function, it must be differentiable, with non-trivial gradients.**

For instance, in image classification, [accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51979012/1714410) is the most common measure of success. However, if you try to differentiate accuracy, you'll see that the gradients are zero almost everywhere and therefore one cannot train a model with accuracy as a loss function.
Similarly, IoU, in its native form, also has meaningless gradients and cannot be used as a loss function. However, [extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51979012/1714410) to IoU that preserve gradients exist and can be effectively used as a loss function for training.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! If I understand this correctly the IOU in its normal form just helps to evaluate the model quality instead of helping it to get better?

Comment: @Mao76 yes. IoU is good for evaluation, but not for training.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please describe in which relation the mAP and IoU are to each other?